# Allow a "check out" "check in" of files?

Tags: revision-control

Do you guys know of a way so that if someone is working on a file (let's say through FTP) that will allow them to "check out" the file, so other people know it's being worked on and they don't overwrite any code?

I know that's a feature that was built into FrontPage years ago when I used it - but not sure if something like that exists on it's own - or maybe some kind of system teams can use to keep track of that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Revision control? I'm not being set up am I?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control

Answer (score 3):

There are two  common ways to do this, on is some sort of version control to contain your files and have users check them in and out when using them, however this involves your users learning version control.

The other is to use something like Sharepoint or other document management systems that will give you a document repository (often online) and the ability to check files in and out. The advantage of Sharepoint is that it integrates well with office if this is something you need.