# Windows File Sharing with Check in / Check out feature

Tags: file-sharing, windows-sbs

Similar to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/118152/allow-a-check-out-check-in-of-files), but what I want is a check in / out feature that is built in to Windows File Sharing. The server it would run on is a Windows SBS 2011 server, and the clients will all be Vista or 7. Microsoft Office is a *small* set of files that they need access to, but that is not the main concern

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any check in/check out feature of the File Server role that I'm aware of but Sharepoint in SBS 2011 has that feature. You would need to migrate your documents to a Sharepoint Document Library in order to to make use of it.

I'm not positive but this Sharepoint capability might be limited to Microsoft Office documents.

Comment: It's not just limited to MS Office documents, but the integration and automatic checkin/checkout is.  I've used SharePoint for `.txt` and `.html` based files and been able to check them in and out just fine.  And I'm not positive, but I think you can manually checkin and checkout files of any filetype.